# I am getting the following errors saying 'Could not freeze ./node_modules/

Tags: reactjs, graphql, node-modules, prisma-graphql

I'm building a web app using GraphQL and React. When compiling the front-end/client I see the following errors:

[image: ct]

Is there something else I can provide to help debug this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By the looks of it you are (or your build tool is) using [hard-source-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/mzgoddard/hard-source-webpack-plugin). This is a bug [the issue of which is here](https://github.com/mzgoddard/hard-source-webpack-plugin/pull/419).

[One solution](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/5243#issuecomment-423515702) seems to be:

```
rm -rf node_modules/.cache
```

But it's hard to tell if this will help you.

I would consult the plugin repo.

Comment: For those extra cautious with `rm -rf` :-). `cd node_modules/.cache; rm -rf hard-source` worked for me.

Comment: It's a temporary solution. It reoccurs after then second webpack.

Comment: I don't have a `.cache` in my `node_modules` folder.